# jQuery remove and add a div back when the text in a div has changed

Tags: jquery

I have a div slideshow.  I have several divs with a class named rotate in each one of them and there are more divs within that div.  My task is to check if one of the divs which have a postfix as _note3 contain a 0 to exclude that slide from the slideshow.  The zero would be coming from a SQL server.  I am able to exclude it from the slideshow but I have been unable to put it back in when the zero is removed.  I am wondering if someone has any idea what I am doing wrong and help me find a solution.

My code looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var note3 = [];
    var divsCount = 0;
    var ids = [];
    var count = 0;
    var divs = [];
    var removed = [];

    for(var x = 0; x < $(".rotate").length; x++) {
        notes3(divsCount);
        getRotate(divsCount);
        divsCount++;
    }
    // I find all the _note3 divs
    function notes3(index) {
        note3.push($('div[id*="_note3"]:eq(' + index + ')').attr("id"));
    }

    for (var t = 0; t < $(".rotate").length; t++) {
        $(".rotate").eq(t).hide();

    }
    // I find put all the rotate divs in an array
    function getRotate(index) {
        divs.push($('div[class*="rotate"]:eq(' + index + ')').attr("class"));
    }

    // This is where my rotation happens
    function setsRotation() {




        $(".rotate").eq(count).hide();
        if (count < $(".rotate").length - 1) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
        }

// If it contains a zero I remove it
    if($("#" + note3[count] + "").text() === $.trim("0")) {
// I put the div index in an array
        removed.push(count);
        $('div[class*="rotate"]:eq(' + count + ')').remove();
        // If it does not contain a zero
    } else {

    // If the index is in the removed array I take it out and append the div
        if($.inArray(count, removed) > - 1) {

            removed.splice($.inArray(count, removed), 1);

            $("#slideshow").append(divs[count]);
        }

        $('div[class*="rotate"]:eq(' + count + ')').show();

    }
    }
    setInterval(setsRotation, 1000);
    });
```

Thanks in advanced!

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="rotate" id="jrkC">
<div>
        <div id="JerkChknLg_desc" class="descript"></div><div id="JerChknLg_note3"></div>
    <table class="pepper">

    <tr>
        <td class="size">Regular ds</td>
        <td class="size">Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="value"><div id="JerkChknSm_price"></div></td>
        <td class="value"><div id="JerkChknLg_price"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="frontPic"><img src="media/img/JerkChkn.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="rotate" id="soups" >
<div  id="">
        <div id="SoupLrg_desc" class="descript"></div><div id="SoupLrg_note3"></div>
    <table class="pepper">

    <tr>
        <td class="size">Regular</td>
        <td class="size">Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="value"><div id="SoupSm_price"></div></td>
        <td class="value"><div id="SoupLrg_price"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="frontPic"><img src="media/img/Soup.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html also? a jsfiddle would be good for us to understand your problem better

Comment: Hi Sergio.  Probably jsfiddle would not work the same since the data including the zero is extracted from a database using a VB script.  I have found that using static data gives different results in this case.

Comment: Great, now its more clear. I don't see any div with `_note3 ` on name, id or other attr. Can you explain more were it should appear?

Comment: It might be better for you to assign `$("#" + note3[count] + "")` to an object - this will allow you to control it and manipulate it as you need without losing the context - even if you change the id.

Comment: Sorry, the _note3 is a postfix to several IDs.  You can find one in the fourth line JerChknLg_note3.  The next one is SoupLrg_note3.

Comment: In function note3 I add the note3 ids

Comment: Where do you suggest I make that change Rijvi?

Comment: You should use `$('div[id$="_note3"]')` to select the div with ID ending with _note3, but where is the `0`? in the html inside the div or a attr? data- field would be the best here

Comment: The 0 comes from a database.  A VB script pulls the data values a places them within the proper div ids.

Comment: Ok, how would it look like? id = `SoupLrg0_note3` or `SoupLrg_0_note3`? so we know were to look

Comment: It would look like this once it is pulled out: <div id="SoupLrg_note3">0</div>

Comment: The you need `if($('div[id$="_note3"]').text() == 0)` to check that

Comment: That did not work.  It does not remove the div now.

Comment: My script checks for values fine.  My only problem is how to append the div that I previously removed when the note3 div within it had a 0.